# How to convert multibyte UTF-8 std::string to NSString?

Tags: c++, objective-c, ios, utf-8, cocos2d-iphone

I have a set of C++ `std::string`, of which some have multibyte characters such as `á`, `ä`, `ç`, `ß` or `ñ`. When I convert them to `NSString` using `NSString stringWithUTF8String:`, the resulting strings contain weird characters that can not be rendered.

I have also tried `NSString stringWithCString:encoding`, but I haven't found any encoding that works.

What am I doing wrong?

--

I have finally solved it. The conversion was well done but the characters didn't show on the debugger when it was connected to the phone, but were well displayed when connected to the debugger. The problem I had in my program was that the text renderer did not support some special characters...

Comment: Please paste a sample of the content of that `std::string`.

Comment: In the text file, there is a string like this: áäñ, which is "C3 A1 C3 A4 C3 B1" encoded as UTF8 (please note that every character needs two bytes).

Comment: If I store it in a str::string, length() returns 6, but if I cout<< it, it's well printed.

Comment: In that case `-stringWithUTF8String:` should work. How are you calling this method?

Comment: I have just tested this:
`char * testChar = "áéíäñ";
    string testString = testChar;
    NSString * testNS = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:testChar];
    
    int testCharLen = strlen(testChar);
    int testStringLen = testString.length();
    int testNSLen = [testNS length];
    int testNSLen2 = [testNS2 length];`
And everything runs well in the simulator, but not in the phone.

Comment: Consider removing the cocos2d-iphone tag.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to pass the std::string directly or are you using the c_str() method? This should work:

```
std::string s = "á ä ç ß ñ";
[NSString stringWithUTF8String: s.c_str()];
```